# keep greasepencil strokes visible when zooming out (it's fading, not clipped)

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil

I use grease pencil to take notes by hand directly in the viewport.
I like to zoom in and out to move around and/or have a full view of all my notes.
However, since 2.83, when I zoom out the strokes fade to white and disappear. Kind of like a fog with distance.
The fact that they get thinner when zooming out is a good point, however I'd like to always see them, whatever zoom out I apply, a bit like when using the setting "Display as Wire".
That was perfect in 2.82.
The problem is still here in 2.90.

Actually the variation of the thickness is not a problem for me, on the contrary it is something I expect and like. In that regard I am not very fan of the annotations for which indeed the thickness is fixed even when moving out, making my text unreadable! (plus grease pencil is much more pleasant and has more features). Same problem with the stroke thickness connected to world space.
My problem is more about the “fading” of the strokes, the fact that the further I move out the brighter is my stroke.
I wish there would be an option or a modifier to be able to keep it full dark like it used to be in 2.82 (like the last image on my screenshot above).
Or maybe an option in the draw engine.
So I am stuck to the version 2.82a, but I am already sad to not be able to use some new grease pencil features of the 2.83 (e.g. the option “scale stroke thickness”).

Actually, building blender is pretty easy, at the current version at least. (using the source code at https://github.com/blender/blender)
So I wish I could spot the place in the code where I could tweak this fading part.
However I have no idea where to look in the code, I might try to find in which commit the change append but not easy as the compiling has error on every previous commit version I try :confused:

Bellow some screenshots of some grease pencil strokes and how they fade away when zooming out in 2.83 and further. And the same file in 2.82a, the strokes always remain visible :

**Edit :**
Ok I compiled all the commits since 2.82a to finally spot the one commit where it goes wrong:
https://github.com/blender/blender/commit/33c0861db89b2c0d67df6ae99d91ab64bca2562b
accordingly to the commit page, only 2 files are slightly changed.
However, when I checkout the commit just before (git checkout a5c4a44df67), I have a huge number of files changed.
I really do not get it :/
Even if I list all the commit from all the branches (git log --branches=*) I still see that commit (a5c4a44df67) to be the previous one.
(also the previous one if I list only the commits of the branch greasepencil-object)

Anyway the number of files changed is to huge to spot where my tweak should be.

I guess I have a misunderstanding of how git works.
Are there some commits in-between that I could get somewhere?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could it be connected to the anti-aliasing? On the render properties, there is a new "grease pencil" section with an anti-aliasing option but that doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: You can choose to have the stroke thickness be in screen space or in world space. https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Vql.png

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However the variation of the thickness is not a problem for me, on the contrary it is something I expect and like. In that regard I am not very fan of the annotations for which indeed the thickness is fixed even when moving out, making my text unreadable! (plus grease pencil is much more pleasant and has more features). Same problem with the stroke thickness connected to world space.
My problem is more about the “fading” of the strokes, the fact that the further I move out the brighter is my stroke.

Comment: I wish there would be an option or a modifier to be able to keep it full dark like it used to be in 2.82 (like the last image on my screenshot above).
Or maybe an option in the draw engine.
So I am stuck to the version 2.82a, but I am already sad to not be able to use some new grease pencil features of the 2.83 (e.g. the option “scale stroke thickness”).

Comment: I updated my initial post with those points

Answer (score 0):

Your strokes will fade away and become thinner when you zoom out if you don't have *Self Overlap* enabled in *Grease Pencil* under material properties . If you enable it, at least I found, that strokes didn't fade away or thin out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (that I read a bit later...)
However on my side I do not see any difference when the Self Overlap option is checked ; the stoke will still fade away :/